# unable to convert float to int in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, int

I want to convert a column which has values -1.0, 0.0 and Nans to int. I have tried both `pd.tonumeric` and also `myCol.astype`

```
myCol = pd.to_numeric(myCol,downcast='signed', errors = 'coerce')
myCol.astype(np.int64, errors= 'ignore')
```

None of these approaches work. 
Desired input and output

```
input: myCol = pd.Series([np.nan, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0])
output: Nan, 0, -1, 0, 0, 2
```

Thanks.

Comment: What `int` value do you expect for `NaN`?

Comment: What are the inputs, what are the outputs, and what are the desired outputs? Samples can help us diagnose the issue

Comment: @G.Anderson Sorry about that. Just edited.

Comment: And what are your current outputs given that input?

Comment: An unfortunate feature of pandas is that any numeric column with NaN becomes a float data type automatically.  You could convert to a string and trim.  However the column would be data type 'object'.

Comment: `myCol.astype(str).str.split('.', expand=True)[0].tolist()`  But, I don't think this gives you the output you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately NaN is a floating point number on its own (please check the IEEE 754 floating-point standard).  Therefore, unless you drop the rows with NaNs, your conversion to `int` will always fail!

Your approach of using `astype` is correct otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to create strings:

```
myCol.astype(str).str.split('.', expand=True)[0].tolist()
```

Output:

```
['nan', '0', '-1', '0', '0', '2']
```